How Do I Switch the VSCode Debugger from Chrome to Brave Browser?
I get the following error: Unable to launch browser: "spawn S:\Program Files (x86)\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe EACCES"
       LAUNCH.JSON FILE:

{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [{     
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch chrome against localhost",
    "url": "http://localhost:8080",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/public",
    "runtimeExecutable": "S:\\Program Files (x86)\\BraveSoftware\\Brave- 
    Browser\\Application\\brave.exe"
}
]
}

   SETTINGS.JSON FILE: 

{   
"files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
"editor.fontSize": 18,
"editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
"[javascript]": {
"editor.formatOnSave": true
},
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
"workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
"prettier.semi": false,
"liveServer.settings.ChromeDebuggingAttachment": true,
"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "S:\\Program Files   
(x86)\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-   
Browser\\Application\\brave.exe",
}

Tried changing the settings in the JSON files, to no avail.

EACCES suggests a permissions issue. If you go to Properties > Security for brave.exe does it show that you have read and execute permissions?

So, it didn't show that I had read and execute permissions for each user. I have enabled 'full control' on all now, but I'm getting the same error message. Any idea? Here's the before: https://ibb.co/7thG9qs   and after: https://ibb.co/g9PrrTb

Hmm, are you able to open Brave through the command line?

Yes, I am able to.

So, I got Brave to work with it. I had Brave set to 'open as Administrator', so I turned that off and the window popped right up.
